# Appendix: Sections without Chapter-Counter

Tags: numbering, appendices

I'm using the documentclass `scrbook`. When starting the `appendix` it will give me something like:

```
A. Some chapter
A.1. Some section
A.2. Some section
A.2.1. Some subsection
```

The figures will be like `A.1`, `A.2`, etc.

I'm looking for a way to remove the Chapter-Counter from the (sub)section-titles in order to get:

```
A. Some chapter
1. Some section
2. Some section
2.1. Some subsection
```

While the figures should still be `A.1`, `A.2`, etc.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: the answer by @cmhughes will nicely do what you ask, but a warning: if you want to `\ref` them elsewhere, the useful/necessary context won't be there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but my appendices will be independent from the rest of the document. Everything can be understood without reading anything there. It is intended for these who are not familiar with some aspects of mathematics or physics and therefore I will never `\ref` anything directly. Nevertheless this is a good point for those who want something like this on other intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the line

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

immediately after `\appendix` then you get the output you want.

[image: screenshot]

Here's a complete MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```