# Remove label A from Appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I'm using the appendix package to format my thesis.
The issue is in the naming of the Appendix within the TOC.

Currently it looks like this: APPENDIX A

> LIST OF TABLES....................................... iv
>
> LIST OF FIGURES...................................... v ...
>
> APPENDIX A ........................................ 15
>
> BIBLIOGRAPHY....................................... 25

How do I force LaTeX to remove the A?

Below is the MWE I'm using.

```
%\listfiles

\documentclass[lscape]{msu-thesis}
% lscape option is needed for this sample file to show correct placement
% of page numbers on landscape pages. If you don't have any landscape pages
% in your document, you don't need to load this option.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% If you need newlines in your title, you must use \protect\\
\title{Topics in the Syntax and Semantics of Phonology}
\author{Joe Linguist}
\fieldofstudy{Linguistics}
\dedication{This thesis is dedicated to someone.}
\date{2010}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{cgloss}
\usepackage{natbib}



\counterwithin{exx}{chapter}
\bibliographystyle{unified}
\singlegloss
% Uncomment the next two lines for single spaced examples with gb4e
%\let\oldexe\exe
%\renewcommand{\exe}{\SingleSpacing\oldexe}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitlepage
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\makecopyrightpage
\makededicationpage
\clearpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\DoubleSpacing
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\SingleSpacing
\tableofcontents* % ToC will not appear in the table of contents
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
% The next command changes chapters in the TOC to have no dotted leader
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftnodots}}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

% Uncomment this next command if you have more than one appendix
%\appendicestrue
% This command creates the cover page for the appendix/appendices
\makeappendixcover
\appendix
\chapter{An appendix}
\lipsum[9-15]
\backmatter
% The next command forces the Bibliography to have a dotted leader
% (May not be required)
\addtocontents{toc}{%
   \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}}
\SingleSpacing
% This command creates the cover page for the bibliography
\makebibliographycover

\bibliography{MSU-thesis-testfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If the appendix is not labeled as `A`, how will readers know what `Figure A.1, A.2, etc` means (from your comment)?

Comment: Well, the figures need to be labeled A.1, etc.,  but this is the note I received from my grad school :/ • TABLE OF CONTENTS: APPENDIX A: Since you only have one appendix, this heading should simply say APPENDIX. Remove the “A”.

Comment: @JasonMatney, please provide an MWE as requested by Christian above. If I assume the `book` document class, remove the undefined `\makeappendixcover` command, and add a `\tableofcontents` and `\end{document}`, no text "APPENDIX A" or "APPENDIX" is generated in the table of contents.

Comment: Your example is not minimal at all. Reduce it to the _smallest possible document_ that exhibits your problem. And since `msu-thesis` is [on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/msu-thesis), there's really no need to include it here.

Comment: Hopefully that'll do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perhaps, what you want:

Use a `\chapter*{\appendixname}` having no 'number' (i.e. no prefix 'A') and just provide the `\thefigure` with the prefix `A`, via

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}
```

Additionally, add the `Appendix` to the TOC using

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}
```

manually.

See code below, where I commented some commands leading to errors. The MWE is definitely too large ;-)

```
\documentclass[lscape]{msu-thesis}
% lscape option is needed for this sample file to show correct placement
% of page numbers on landscape pages. If you don't have any landscape pages
% in your document, you don't need to load this option.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% If you need newlines in your title, you must use \protect\\
\title{Topics in the Syntax and Semantics of Phonology}
\author{Joe Linguist}
\fieldofstudy{Linguistics}
\dedication{This thesis is dedicated to someone.}
\date{2010}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{gb4e}
%\usepackage{cgloss}
\usepackage{natbib}



\counterwithin{exx}{chapter}
\bibliographystyle{unified}
\singlegloss
% Uncomment the next two lines for single spaced examples with gb4e
%\let\oldexe\exe
%\renewcommand{\exe}{\SingleSpacing\oldexe}

\let\standardthefigure\thefigure%

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitlepage
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum
\end{abstract}
\clearpage
\makecopyrightpage
\makededicationpage
\clearpage
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\DoubleSpacing
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage
\SingleSpacing
\tableofcontents* % ToC will not appear in the table of contents
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
% The next command changes chapters in the TOC to have no dotted leader
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftnodots}}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

% Uncomment this next command if you have more than one appendix
%\appendicestrue
% This command creates the cover page for the appendix/appendices
\makeappendixcover
%\appendix
\chapter*{An appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}%
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}%

\begin{figure}
\caption{A dummy figure}
\caption{Another dummy figure}%
\end{figure}

\lipsum[9-15]
\backmatter
% The next command forces the Bibliography to have a dotted leader
% (May not be required)
\addtocontents{toc}{%
   \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}}
\SingleSpacing

\let\thefigure\standardthefigure% Backstorage of traditional numbering for figures
% This command creates the cover page for the bibliography
%\makebibliographycover

%\bibliography{MSU-thesis-testfile}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!  This was the solution...  
\begin{appendices}
\makeappendixcover
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDIX}
\setcounter{figure}{0} \renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{table}{0} \renewcommand{\thetable}{A.\arabic{table}}

Comment: @JasonMatney: It's alright, but be more specific next time, please. It was not easy to figure out what you requested! Happy Texing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yuo need to redefine the chapter counter right when the appendix part is started. Here is your MWE:

```
\documentclass[lscape]{msu-thesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Some section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\appendix

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{} %% Here we redefine the chapter counter
\chapter{My appendix}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}} %%And here we redefine it back

\begin{figure}
\caption{Figure one}
\caption{Figure two}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[9-15]
\end{document}
```

Very similar question was discussed here: [Appendix: Sections without Chapter-Counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119400/appendix-sections-without-chapter-counter)

Comment: Probably `\thefigure` uses `\thechapter`, leading to an empty chapter number reference, it is `Fig .1`, `Fig .2`. This would also lead to unnumbered appendix chapters

Comment: @Christian Hupfer We can redefine it back after the chapter command:
    `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}`
    `\chapter{My appendix}`
    `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}`

Comment: Yes, and what about the figure numbers within `appendix` ;-)

Comment: Better save the definition of the `\thechapter` before via a `\let\standardthechapter\thechapter` and then store it back afterwards, to keep the numbering consistent

Comment: @Christian Hupfer - The figures in appendix are numbered correctly if we redefine the chapter counter back.